# How can I add a new callback for Flutter's Material Slider Widget to access touch active/inactive status?

Tags: flutter, event-handling

I'm using Flutter's Material slider.dart and the official widget supports callbacks for **`onChanged`**, **`onChangeEnd`**, and **`onChangeStart`**.  These start and end callbacks are a bit odd though in that they trigger on a quick tap of the slider, as well as a touch and slide of the slider that's still being held, and then they fire again when the slider thumb is released.  What I really need to know is when the slider is FULLY released (from either a quick tap OR a touch and slide).

So I have found a way to edit `.../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/Material/slider.dart` in a way that prints out to the console the status I need.  I look at all handleEvent calls and added the following to know when touch was up or down 
(**see the change using event.runtimeType**):

```
  @override
  void handleEvent(PointerEvent event, BoxHitTestEntry entry) {
    if (event.runtimeType == PointerDownEvent) {
      _touchActive = true;
      print("---------Down!---------");
    } else if (event.runtimeType == PointerUpEvent) {
      _touchActive = false;
      print("---------Up!---------");
    }
    assert(debugHandleEvent(event, entry));
    if (event is PointerDownEvent && isInteractive) {
      // We need to add the drag first so that it has priority.
      _drag.addPointer(event);
      _tap.addPointer(event);
    }
  }
```

But now I need to somehow get that data back out of the widget through a callback.  The callback can be similar to any of the three mentioned earlier such as onChangeStart or onChangeEnd, but I'm not sure where all I need to update to create this.  Can anyone help point me to how to add this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to add additional members of the `Slider` class similar to `final ValueChanged<double> onChangeStart;` and add them to the constructor.

When you wanted to trigger your new event, you would call them, similar to: `widget?.onChangeStart(_lerp(value));` (I added the `?` in case your call back is null. Equally you could assert that it is not like: `assert(widget.onChangeStart != null);`)

Aside - rather than `event.runtimeType == PointerDownEvent` you could use `event is PointerDownEvent`

Comment: Ok, I tried this, I was able to add ValueChanged<bool>.  There were a lot of places to add the new member!  Thanks for the "is" tip.  That's great to know.